# Tuple to list with multiple elements originally separated by \r\n in Erlang

Tags: list, ftp, erlang, tuples

I'm writing a program which gets the list of the files in an FTP server.
So it starts like that :

```
inet_parse:address(IP),
inets:start(),
{ok, Pid} = inets:start(ftpc, [{host, IP}]),
ftp:user(Pid, "anonymous", "lol@lol.com"),
ftp:pwd(Pid),
Content = ftp:ls(Pid),
```

The Content variable is  a tuple, and returns something like that :

```
7> Content = ftp:ls(Pid).
{ok,"-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 bar\r\ndrwxr-xr-x    2 21       21           4096 Oct 14 21:47 baz\r\n-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 foo\r\nlrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     10             21 Sep 10 14:22 musique -> /home/foo/musique\r\n"}
```

I know I can convert this tuple to a list, but I want to know if I can get each element (which are separated by a \r\n) so I can access them individually (in order to save them in a database, for example).
Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, Rubber and Roberto :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1> {ok,S} = {ok,"-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 bar\r\ndrwxr-xr-x    2 21       21           4096 Oct 14 21:47 baz\r\n-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 foo\r\nlrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     10             21 Sep 10 14:22 musique -> /home/foo/musique\r\n"}.
{ok,"-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 bar\r\ndrwxr-xr-x    2 21       21           4096 Oct 14 21:47 baz\r\n-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 foo\r\nlrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     10             21 Sep 10 14:22 musique -> /home/foo/musique\r\n"}
2> Split = string:tokens(S,"\r\n").
["-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 bar",
 "drwxr-xr-x    2 21       21           4096 Oct 14 21:47 baz",
 "-rw-r--r--    1 21       21              0 Oct 14 21:47 foo",
 "lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     10             21 Sep 10 14:22 musique -> /home/foo/musique"]
3>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function string:tokens/2, however it takes a string as a list of separators so each character of the string is a separator. Calling

```
string:tokens(Content, "\r\n")
```

will work for your case, but in general it does not exactly what you need. Here is an example of function which takes a string (multicharacter) as a separator:

```
tokens(Str, Separator) ->
    tokens(Str, Separator, []).

tokens(Str, Separator, Acc) ->
    case string:str(Str, Separator) of
        0 ->
            lists:reverse([Str | Acc]);
        N ->
            Token = string:substr(Str, 1, N-1),
            Str1 = string:substr(Str, N + string:len(Separator)),
            tokens(Str1, Separator, [Token | Acc])
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ok, Content} = ftp:ls(Pid),
string:tokens(Content, "\r\n").
```